# php get the values from the array as like format

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => T-shirts
    [1] => Evening Dresses
    [2] => Dresses
    [3] => Clothes
)
```

Here I want to get the values of the array and add "" for each values and add , after each value
So the valus should finally come like this

```
IN("T-shirts","Evening Dresses","Dresses","Clothes")
```

so for this I made my code like this

```
$category_pool = '';
foreach($categoryArray as $categoryArr)
    $category_pool .= $categoryArr.',';
    $category_pool = ((strpos($category_pool, ',') === false) ? (' = '.$category_pool.' ') : (' IN ("'.rtrim($category_pool, ',').'") '));
```

But here it is getting the value like

```
 IN ("T-shirts,Evening Dresses,Dresses,Clothes")
```

So can someone tell me how to make this value to come like

```
 IN("T-shirts","Evening Dresses","Dresses","Clothes")
```

Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick solution is:

change your fragment:

```
$category_pool = '';
foreach($categoryArray as $categoryArr)
    $category_pool .= $categoryArr.',';
    $category_pool = ((strpos($category_pool, ',') === false) ? (' = '.$category_pool.' ') : (' IN ("'.rtrim($category_pool, ',').'") '));
```

with one my line:

```
$category_pool = 'IN ( "' . implode('","',$categoryArray).'")';
```

Comment: so I don't have to use `$category_pool .= $categoryArr.',';`

Comment: I have no idea what is `$category_pool` stands for :-)

Comment: I used your code but its showing its showing `implode(): Invalid arguments passed`
The code is like this
$category_pool = ((strpos($category_pool, ',') === false) ? (' = '.$category_pool.' ') : ('IN ( "' . implode('","',$category_pool).'")'));

Comment: I've updated an answer. but still not understand how MY implode could get error message, by the way your `foreach` published is not completed... but I hope you can understand what you should do

Answer (score 1):

```
'IN(' 
. implode(
     ',', 
     array_map(function ($val) {
         return sprintf('"%s"', $val);
     }, $categoryArray)
  ) 
. ')';
```